# How to use a hex value for SVG in FireFox

Tags: css, firefox, svg, sass

I'm loading an SVG URL into a web page using a CSS class. This works in every browser I've tested except Firefox 35.0.1 (and probably earlier versions of Firefox). I've noticed that when using an actual color name, e.g., white, for the stroke, it works as expected, but when I use a hex value, e.g, #ffffff, it does not show a stroke at all. According to MDN, [hex values are supported](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Fills_and_Strokes?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=SVG%2FTutorial%2FFills_and_Strokes).

So, this works fine:

```css
.ui-stroke-icon .ui-icon-head:after,
    background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 540 540" enable-background="new 0 0 540 540" xml:space="preserve"><path fill="none" stroke="white" stroke-width="8" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="...svg coordinates here..."/></svg>
```

But this does not:

```css
.ui-stroke-icon .ui-icon-head:after,
    background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 540 540" enable-background="new 0 0 540 540" xml:space="preserve"><path fill="none" stroke="#ffffff" stroke-width="8" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="...svg coordinates here..."/></svg>
```

Is there any way I can use a hex value for the color here? This would really help keep my Sass as dry as possible.

Answer (score 104, accepted):

The character # is [reserved in URLs](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2.3) as the start of a fragment identifier. You must encode this as %23 for the URL to be valid. This is not a Firefox bug.

Alternatively you could encode the whole string using base64.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. After trying so many silly things like trying to color to `rgba`, etc this finally worked. I think it's always important to understand why something is not working instead of just assuming that it's a bug in the browser.

Comment: This is also a solution for Android's WebView when you want to read svg with [ resources.openRawResource() ] and then load it with [ webView.loadData(svg, "image/svg+xml", "utf-8") ]. For [ webView.loadUrl("file:///android_res/raw/image.svg") ] case it is possible to set color with #